# How to solve error with spread operator in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm a Kotlin developer but I'm working on a java project, but when converting the classes through the sdk, this error appears.
How to solve?

```
fun deviceIsConnected(): Boolean {
    var connected = false
    val myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
    if (myBluetoothAdapter != null && myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
        if (configsAndModels!!.strMACPROBE != null && configsAndModels.strMACPROBE != "") {
            val myDevice = myBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(
                configsAndModels.strMACPROBE
            )
           try {
                val m = myDevice.javaClass.getMethod("isConnected", null as Array<Class<*>>?)) //ERROR ON THIS LINE
               connected =  m.invoke(myDevice, *null as Array<Any?>?) as Boolean //ERROR ON THIS LINE
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                throw IllegalStateException(e)
            }
        }
    }
    return connected
}
```

JAVA :

```
 public boolean deviceIsConnected() {

    boolean connected = false;
    BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (myBluetoothAdapter != null && myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        if (configsAndModels.getStrMACPROBE() != null && !configsAndModels.getStrMACPROBE().equals("")) {
            BluetoothDevice myDevice = myBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(configsAndModels.getStrMACPROBE());

            try {
                Method m = myDevice.getClass().getMethod("isConnected", (Class[]) null);
                connected = (boolean) m.invoke(myDevice, (Object[]) null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    return connected;
}
```

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what your Java code looked like, or which method you're trying to get a reference to. Are you familiar with how to use varags in Kotlin? You can't spread a nullable array. Any why would you try to pass `null` for the class type parameter of a method? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I edited the question with code in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java code is explicitly passing a null array as the varargs, which is unnecessary. You could simplify your Java code to the following, which implicitly passes an empty array:

```java
Method m = myDevice.getClass().getMethod("isConnected");
connected = (boolean) m.invoke(myDevice);
```

Likewise, in Kotlin, you can omit the varargs if you're passing zero values:

```kotlin
val m = myDevice.javaClass.getMethod("isConnected")
connected = m.invoke(myDevice) as Boolean
```

Java allows the null array for backward compatibility (to versions that used arrays instead of varargs) and because it doesn't have null safety. Since Kotlin doesn't need the backward compatibility, it doesn't need to support null arrays.